# Small mail order perennials - OK to plant now?

Tags: planting, perennials

I've just received a load of mail-ordered perennial plants, things like vinca minor. They're quite small, some don't even have any visible plant part. Here in the UK it's pretty cold at the moment, below zero at night.. Am I OK to just wait 'till next week when it's going to get a little warmer, to plant them out in to the garden, or should I be doing something else with them?

Comment: Are they potted or bare-root?

Comment: They’re potted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't let them dry out it should be fine to wait until next week when it's forecast to get warmer. I've just taken the dog for a walk (I live in Essex) and the ground is frozen solid - no point trying to plant into that. When the ground has thawed out, plant them as soon as you can, don't let them dry out and keep the surrounding soil weed free.

Comment: Also, keep them somewhere cool or cold if possible. An unheated garage or garden shed would be ideal. They are hardy, after all. You don't want to keep them somewhere warm for a week and start them into growth, and then plant them outside and check them again for another month or two until spring "really" arrives.